# Is there any better way to write device file instead of having multiple writes?

Tags: c

Actually, I want to blink the led three times in my Linux device.

I can achieve this by writing 1 and 0 simply testing as `echo "1" > /dev/ipuc/ledd`

I want this to be in C program, it ended up like this, I want to avoid so many writes. Below code is laymen implementation, write will have return code for better false proof.

Code

```
static char *ledd = "/dev/ipuc/ledd";
int fd = -1;
if( (fd = open(ledd, O_RDWR ) ) == -1 )
{
        perror( ledd );
}
write(fd, "1", 1);
write(fd, "0", 1);
write(fd, "1", 1);
write(fd, "0", 1);
write(fd, "1", 1);
write(fd, "0", 1);
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: `write(fd,"101010",6)` ?

Comment: @I tried for loop but I want to know other ways as well.

Comment: Add some `usleep(300000);`  between the `write`-s

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes sleep is needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not write all the data at once?

```
char towrite[] = "101010";
write(fd,towrite,sizeof(towrite));  // or strlen if char pointer
```

one write, 6 bytes written.

The timings may differ from a code with 6 calls to `write`, though. And if you have to wait between writes, well, you can't obviously write all the data at once (same problem as [Print a string char by char with a delay after each char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891219/print-a-string-char-by-char-with-a-delay-after-each-char))

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I can write all those bytes as one string. This is simple.

Comment: I suspect this will blink the led at ludicrous speed.  (not that the original code would go much slower...)

Comment: yeah, just edited. If the original code had a delay, that wouldn't be equivalent. Probably useful in a night club :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia So it goes to plaid?  :-D

Answer (score 6):

Combining answers and comments:

```
char sequence[] = "1101001"; // Whatever sequence here 
char *s = sequence;

while (*s)
{
    write(fd, *s++, 1);
    usleep(300000); // Or some other delay facility
}
```

If you just want to blink it `COUNT / 2` times:

```
unsigned int i;

for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
{
    write(fd, '0' + (i % 2), 1);
    usleep(300000); // Or some other delay facility
}
```

or if you want to blink it forever:

```
unsigned int i = 0;
while(1)
{
    i ^= 1; // Toggle  LSB
    write(fd, '0' + i, 1);
    usleep(300000); // Or some other delay facility
}
```

Comment: I would have used `const` for the pointer. otherwise, yes, that's the way

Comment: Thanks for the answer. suggestion 2 is the right choice, I want to blink it for certain times, upvoted it.